# What is the intuition behind Euler's proof of the value of the Riemann Zeta Function at 2?

Tags: intuition, riemann-zeta

I just read the idea of Euler's proof that $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. He studied the Taylor series of the function $\frac{\sin \pi x}{x}$.

Does someone know if he by chance was studying this function and found the connection with the Riemann Zeta Function? Or did he have some intuition that this was the right function to work with?

Comment: @reuns, it is my (naive) impression that this idea came only some decades later, after Euler's epiphany that maybe $\sin(x)$ had an infinite-product expansion... Is there tangible evidence that Euler had contemplated the partial fraction expansion instead? I'd be interested to hear...

Comment: @paulgarrett Isn't his late rigorous proof equivalent to the partial fraction of $\tan(x)$ ?

Comment: @reuns, yes, I have that impression, but/and the earlier epiphany has always struck me as an exemplar of inspiration and methodological optimism. My other example is (perhaps "of course") Riemann's paper on zeta, which I've come to appreciate as astonishingly "courageous", methodologically... I do think that earlier inspirations deserve notice... apart from later justifications. Of course I do like proofs, but especially of provocative things. :)

Comment: The "intuition" is that $f(z)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}-\frac1{z^2} = \sum_{n\ne 0} \frac1{(z-n)^2}$  so that $f^{(2k)}(0)=(2k+2)!\zeta(2k+2)$

Comment: I believe this is covered in Mathologer's video on ["Euler's crazy pi formula generator"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL_Yzbo1ha4&ab_channel=Mathologer)

Comment: If you know the roots of a polynomial, you can immediately factor the polynomial. It is a typical Eulerian leap to think of $\sin(x)$ as an "infinite degree polynomial" for which we know the roots, and to write down the factorization. What a wonderful idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory *"not a full answer, but too long for comments"*. That being said, this will get you 90% of the way there.

As mentioned in my comment, the idea of the proof is essentially covered in Mathologer's video on ["Euler's crazy pi formula generator"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL_Yzbo1ha4&ab_channel=Mathologer). The difference is we start by looking at Euler's product formula for $\sin x$, which can be manipulated or derived to/from many other series', such as a Taylor series for $\sin(\frac{\pi x}{x})$.

$$\sin x = x\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{3\pi}\right)(\dots)$$

This is the foundation for exploring it's relationship to the zeta function. We begin by looking at pairs of terms, and notice they can be simplified as they bare the of the form of the difference of two squares:

$$\sin x = x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(2\pi)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(3\pi)^2}\right)(\dots)$$

The next step is a bit tricky, and I must admit I don't entirely grasp it (again, better described by Mathologer). The gist of it is that we now essentially get clever with our choices in expanding and grouping specific terms, which yields:

$$\sin x = x+\left(-\frac{1}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}-\frac{1}{(3\pi)^2}-\dots\right)x^3+(\dots)x^5+(\dots)$$

Now, after differentiating thrice, we're left with a series preceded by a very useful $\color{red}{\text{constant}}$.

$$-\cos x = \color{red}{\left(-\frac{1}{\pi^2}-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}-\frac{1}{(3\pi)^2}-\dots\right)6}+(\dots)60x^2+(\dots)$$

Evaluating this at $x=0$ gets rid of all the terms proceeding the constant.

$$\cos 0 =1= \left(\frac{1}{\pi^2}+\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}+\frac{1}{(3\pi)^2}+\dots\right)6$$
Which can trivially be rearranged to find a formula for $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which *just-so-happens* to be of the same form as $\zeta(2)$.
$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots=\zeta(2)$$

QED

As for if Euler knew beforehand that this process would result in a zeta-function-like form, is unclear. As with all long term mathematicians, both inexplicable intuition (as with the case of a lot of Euler's work) and stumbling-upon-by-chance is inevitable.

**Note:** I imagine it to be very difficult to algebraically manipulate these formulas for other values of the zeta function. Hence, I don't believe studying this series for sole the intention of it's general relationship to the zeta function was his intention. Clearly, it's very much related to $\zeta(2)$ and, as I imagine, also consequently related to $\zeta(2k)$ (as those are the values for which $\zeta$ yields multiples of powers of $\pi$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As I think more and more about it I think that Euler probably started with the product formula and eventually realized that it was related to the zeta function. But as you said, what really happened is unclear.